# Synchronizing SourceDataLine with display in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, javasound

I'm creating sound visualizer in Java and I can't find a proper way to synchronize playing sound and displaying the soundwave.

note: snippets below are just sketches, but I  actually tried them all

### Approaches I tried:

1. Using the fact that SourceDataLine.write() blocks until there's space in data line's buffer. That results in buffer always being nearly full and each sample actually being played after having whole buffer flushed. And that means half a second delay.

   ```
   try (SourceDataLine sdl = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(someFormat)) {
               sdl.open(someFormat);
               sdl.start();

       while(true) {
           byte[] samples = getSamplesSomehow();
           sdl.write(samples, 0, samples.length); // <-- blocks
           displaySamples(samples);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Enqueuing data to draw and dequeuing it after whole buffer flushed (frame position increased by buffer size or more). This just didn't work, I'm not sure why.

   ```
   Queue<Data> queue = new LinkedList<Data>();
   try (SourceDataLine sdl = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(someFormat)) {
               sdl.open(someFormat);
               sdl.start();

       while(true) {
           int position = sdl.getFramePosition();
           byte[] samples = getSamplesSomehow();
           Data data = new Data(position, samples); // <-- java bean

           // display
           if (queue.size > 0 && queue.peek().getPosition() < position - sdl.getBufferSize()) {
               byte[] samplesToDisplay = queue.remove().getSamples();
               displaySamples(samplesToDisplay);
           }

           // push new data
           queue.add(data);
           sdl.write(samples, 0, samples.length);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Waiting for buffer to be nearly empty. This works perfectly but introduces busy waiting, CPU usage increases 5 times.

   ```
   try (SourceDataLine sdl = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(someFormat)) {
               sdl.open(someFormat);
               sdl.start();

       while(true) {
           byte[] samples = getSamplesSomehow();
           while(sdl.getBufferSize() - sdl.available() >= data.length); // <-- busy waiting
           sdl.write(samples, 0, samples.length); // <-- doesn't get a chance to block
           displaySamples(samples);
       }
   }
   ```

What is common approach to this problem?

Comment: You could try using a separate thread and querying the line progress using the `DataLine` `getLongFramePosition` or `getMicrosecondPosition` methods.

Comment: Will it not be just busy waiting on another thread?

Comment: No, these calls don't seem to be blocked.

Comment: Could elaborate? I'm not sure if I understood. Using `getFramePosition` is essentialy what I did in approach 2, though without addditional thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On approach #1, ship the data to the visualizer *before* outputting on the SDL.

The visualizer and audio playback should each be in their own threads, probably. So, use thread-safe loose coupling for the data handoff. Maybe give your Visualizer a ConcurrentLinkedQueue, to be used in a FIFO manner, and have your sound thread call that.

A half second delay indicates the SDL buffer is rather huge. You should probably specify a smaller buffer size in the SDL open method. I often use 8K give or take a factor of 2. At 44100 fps 16-bit stereo (four bytes per frame) that should only be a latency of around 0.05 seconds. If the small buffer size leads to dropouts, try doubling it. As an example, the class [AudioCue](https://github.com/philfrei/AudioCue) uses a default buffer size of only 1K for Clip-equivalent playback, but the mixing tool (blending multiple clip-equivalents) is set to a safer 8K as a default.

Depending on how you get your samples, there may be some assembly/disassembly required if the input has a different buffer size than your SDL buffer size. But that should be easy to handle in the sound thread's while loop.